# Borrow Checker being very careful, ' ' is a reference, so the data it referes to cannot be borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm working with Rust and I'm struggling with a certain situation to overcome the Compiliers Borrow checker.

I have a situation where I need to implement a Struct. During the initialization of the implementation, I need to pass a reference to the Struct, `Repo`, to another implementation, before its fully initialized.

The 2nd Struct, `Backend`, implements a connection to a database. After the connection has been made it needs to pull information from the DB, and populates a field of the first Struct. Its during this process the `Backend` Struct needs to be updated with the information from the DB

Here is a MUC.

```
use std::{collections::HashMap, borrow::BorrowMut};
use serde_json::Value;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum BackendError {
    Generic(String),
}

impl From<sqlite::Error> for BackendError{
    fn from(error: sqlite::Error) -> Self{
        BackendError::Generic(error.to_string())
    }
}

pub struct Entry {
    pub version: String,
    pub val: Value,
}

// Information needed by the repository functionality
pub struct Repo{
    pub values: HashMap<String,HashMap<String, Entry>>,
    backend: Box<dyn Backend>
}

impl Repo {
    pub fn new() -> Repo{

        // initialize Persistence backend and load any prior status_values based on backend selection
        let inst = init_backend_provider();

        let repo = Repo {
            values: HashMap::new(),
            backend: inst ,
        };
        
        match repo.backend.load(&repo){

            Ok(s) => s,
            Err(e) => log::error!("{:?}", e),
        }

        repo
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------------

pub trait Backend: Send + Sync{
    fn load(&self, repo: &Repo) -> Result<(), BackendError>; 
}

pub fn init_backend_provider() -> Box<dyn Backend>{

    Box::new(DB::new())
}

pub struct DB{}

impl DB{

    fn new () -> Self{
        DB{}
    }
}

impl Backend for DB{

    fn load(&self, repo: &Repo) -> Result<(), BackendError>{

        // let key_value = repo.values.entry("key".to_string()).or_insert(HashMap::new());

        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main(){

    let repo = Repo::new();
}
```

The error I'm getting is obvious. I can't borrow the data as mutable if its a reference.

I've attempted to pass it as a mutable reference, &mut.
... match repo.backend.load(&mut repo) ...
That  causes the compiler to complain that I'm trying to borrow as mutable from something that is already an immutable borrow. Ok, no problem, lets just make the instance mutable.

```
let mut repo = Repo {
            values: HashMap::new(),
            backend: inst ,
        };
        
match repo.backend.load(&mut repo)
```

Long story, I've tried multiple combinations of making `repo` mutable, and the parameters with no success.

> What I'm trying to do

When I call `load()`, I want to pass the Struct reference. This way I can look at the Hashmap, `Value`. I want to look at that first level entry, either creating a new entry or pulling that entry and updating it. In this situation, it will always need to be created as its part of the initialization process. Once I've created that entry, I'll call the DB and request all available fields of a particular table. This all works, so I'm not overloading the MUC with code that works.

Comment: The parameter of `load` also needs to be mutable `fn load(&self, repo: &mut Repo)`. Then you can pass it as `repo.backend.load(&mut repo)`.

Comment: It is not possible to pass a mutable reference to repo into a function called on data owned by repo.

Comment: You'll have to pass the `values` HashMap into `load` instead.

Comment: @pigeonhands If I do what you suggest, I have an immutable brorrow, that is also trying to borrow as mutable at the same time.

Comment: @PitaJ, thats what I was concerned with. I'm calling a field within Repo, that than modifies Repo. It seems I should Intialize Repo, but leave the inst field blank. Well not blank but don't populate it with backend just yet. What if I set repo.backend as an option, and leave it as None, until I'm ready to insert inst

Comment: Why not have `Backend::load` return a `Repo` instead of modifying one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question you should ask yourself is not "How do I make it mutable?" but instead "How should I really design my structs and interfaces?".

The API you have currently means that initializing a `Backend` requires ... itself? Which is absolute nonsense.

Why do I say that? Because `Backend::load` requires a `&Repo`, which contains a `Backend`. So `load` takes itself as a parameter.

Rust borrow checker is correct in complaining about this; your interpretation of what it complains about is wrong, though. Your problem is not mutability, but that your API makes no sense.

What you should actually do: don't give `Backend::init` a reference to itself. It only requires `values`, so give it that. Then it works:

```rust
use serde_json::Value;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum BackendError {
    Generic(String),
}

impl From<sqlite::Error> for BackendError {
    fn from(error: sqlite::Error) -> Self {
        BackendError::Generic(error.to_string())
    }
}

pub struct Entry {
    pub version: String,
    pub val: Value,
}

// Information needed by the repository functionality
pub struct Repo {
    pub values: HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Entry>>,
    backend: Box<dyn Backend>,
}

impl Repo {
    pub fn new() -> Repo {
        // initialize Persistence backend and load any prior status_values based on backend selection
        let inst = init_backend_provider();

        let mut repo = Repo {
            values: HashMap::new(),
            backend: inst,
        };

        match repo.backend.load(&mut repo.values) {
            Ok(s) => s,
            Err(e) => log::error!("{:?}", e),
        }

        repo
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------------

pub trait Backend: Send + Sync {
    fn load(
        &self,
        values: &mut HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Entry>>,
    ) -> Result<(), BackendError>;
}

pub fn init_backend_provider() -> Box<dyn Backend> {
    Box::new(DB::new())
}

pub struct DB {}

impl DB {
    fn new() -> Self {
        DB {}
    }
}

impl Backend for DB {
    fn load(
        &self,
        values: &mut HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Entry>>,
    ) -> Result<(), BackendError> {
        let key_value = values.entry("key".to_string()).or_insert(HashMap::new());

        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let repo = Repo::new();
}
```

There are of course many other architectural ways to solve this self-referential API. The basic problem is that if `Repo` requires a `Backend`, but `Backend` also requires a `Repo`, your dependency tree isn't a tree, but a circle. You should ask yourself: who really depends on what? And then build a struct layout  whose dependencies are actually a tree.

Comment: It's sometimes hard to see the forest through the trees. More so when someone asks or expects, you to look somewhere else. Thank you! I'll make these changes and justify the change.

Comment: Can you please expand on why `repo.backend.load(&mut repo.values)` doesn't have the a problem of taking both mutable and non-mutable references?  I agree it's no longer a self-reference, but why does this borrow work?  What rule is being exercised there so that they're "sharing" the reference to the parent struct cleanly?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Because `repo` isn't actually borrowed here at all ... `repo.backend` is borrowed, and `repo.values` is borrowed. The rust borrow checker is smart enough to understand that partial borrows of structs don't overlap. The problem before was that the argument of `load` was `&mut Repo`, which borrowed the **entire** `repo` object while `repo.backend` was also borrowed. Those two alias.

Comment: @Finomnis - OK.  I understood the original problem (self-referential), but I wasn't 100% on if `repo.backend` and `repo.values` meant that there was a reference to `repo` or not.  You're saying "no" which I'm OK with.  I guess what I wonder on more is I know you can do it with a function that has `&mut repo: Repo` in its signature, and you can pass its parts on to a subsequent call.  What rule says that's OK?

Comment: @KevinAnderson It is in fact OK :) https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0a245b0bf7843cbd0c1914f1a4dba17b

Comment: @KevinAnderson The borrow checker even allows you to consume a struct piece by piece (note that the structs here can only be moved, not copied/cloned): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8aad5e103189ecc63654b13e38768e61 This is the basic principle of embedded rust hals. The borrow checker checks at compile time if you misuse pins, by moving single pins out of the struct of peripherals.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I might have misunderstood you, however. If you were asking if you could first borrow `&mut repo: Repo` in one call and then borrow a part of it in another call then no; the order does not matter, the important part is that they are not borrowed simultaneously. If the previous call returned, then after that of course, you can do with the `repo` object whatever you want. The reason why we had the problem in the first place is because they were borrowed simultaneously, not sequentially.

Comment: @Finomnis - [Here's my playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=565de6057631077954bda2afe1c4ae8e) on this.  It's where the two components are borrowed _differently_.  And it works through a `&mut` reference.  So it's all good.  The original issue _looks_ like it's two different borrow problem, when really it's a self-reference problem.  My playground there shows how two different borrows on different parts of the struct (even with different access levels) is OK.

Comment: @KevinAnderson *"The original issue looks like it's two different borrow problem, when really it's a self-reference problem."* - Exactly :)